# How to introduce new concept into database table structure for 0..1 instances?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have an issue I've encountered with new requirements and don't know how best to structure my database tables. The situation is basically as follows:

I have employees stored in an Employees table. Due to an increase in production, the company has had to hire many temporary employees. All of these employees, both permanent and temporary employees, have to enter data into an ERP system. So, essentially, employees will be entering "Orders" with the Orders table having a field named "EnteredBy". In an ideal world, I would have both of these two types of employees stored in the Employees table.

Due to the company's different systems in place and groups within the company not talking to each other, some temporary employees do become permanent employees, so we need a way to report on all of the Orders that "new" permanent employee has done while they were "temporary employees" and technically "merge" the data that the temporary employee worked on to their new permanent employee record.

Not all temporary employees will become permanent employees. All orders have to have an "employee" attached to it, i.e. a Foreign Key holding the Employee's unique identifier.

I am stuck on how to incorporate the concept of a "temporary employee" into this data model and still upholding data integrity with Orders.  Any suggestions?

Current DB table structure:

### Employee

- EmployeeID (PK)
- FirstName
- LastName
- ... other attributes

### Order

- OrderID (PK)
- EmployeeID (FK)
- ... other attributes

> UPDATE 1:
> When trying to convey this problem in a database table design was when I decided to seek the advice from the SO experts. In my analysis of a solution via OOP, a design of a [TempEmployee] IS A [Employee], but I wasn't able to wrap my brain on how to convey that into table design and the CRUD operations. FYI, an [Employee] has many fields while a [TempEmployee] has a subset of those fields, thus all of its fields existing in an Employee.

Comment: Show some code which you had tried

Comment: Do you want to save history order placed by ex-employee?

Do you need to identify employee who place the order even is temporary employee?

Comment: I have added further notes: UPDATE 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm assuming that it is possible to load Temporary employees as employees)

Inheritance is a fairly common scenario in modelling - in your case, it seems that can extend the existing Employee structure, so you can model temporary employees as follows:

```
TemporaryEmployee
 - EmployeeID (PK and FK to Employee)
 - StartDate
 - EndDate
 - Other temp employee fields here
```

Because `TemporaryEmployee` IS also an `Employee`, it shares the `Employee` primary key, and referential integrity can be enforced via making `TemporaryEmployee.EmployeeId` a foreign key to `Employee.EmployeeId`.

The integrity of `Orders` is unaffected, since the existing `Employees-Orders` RI is unchanged. 
Another benefit of extending rather than changing is that you haven't changed any of the underlying model, so regression issues caused by your change to your ERP system should be avoided (although testing will still be essential).

**Edit, clarification:**

*Existing ERP System tables:*

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
   EmployeeID INT identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   EmployeeTypeId ? -- e.g. might be able to repurpose to identity Temporary employees?
   -- Other Employee Fields here ... not all of these will be relevant to TemporaryEmployee
);

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
   OrderId INT identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   EmployeeID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
   -- etc.
);
```

Now you extend Employee with another table, without changing the above schema at all:

```
CREATE TABLE TempEmployee
(
   EmployeeID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   -- Other extended fields here as per above

   CONSTRAINT FK_TempEmployee_Employee REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
);
```

Comment: Do you mean that some employeeID will reserved for temporary employees?

Comment: It looks like good idea, but if temporary employees will be hired on regular job then you should change his and his history orders. I not sure but I think that may be complicated.

Comment: @StuartLC - That design was relatively what I had initially thought, BUT I can't understand the EmployeeID part for a TempEmployee. Say TempEmployee with ID=43 becomes a permanent employee and is assigned a system generated ID=753. When a report is run on EmployeeID=753, all of the Orders for ID=43 should come up. Also, another "issue" in grasping this is how can the TempEmployee's EmployeeID be a PK and FK in table design? How would IDs be handled for uniqueness?

Comment: Because TempEmployee reuses EmployeeId's primary key, the PK won't change if the Temp becomes a permanent employe (you can just delete the associated TempEmployee extension record). Redundant Employee fields which aren't applicable for temps will need to be populated with NULL's or Default values - I guess its a good indication of how resilient the ERP system is?

Comment: @StuartLC - I feel your solution is correct and have read it a couple of times to make sure I am getting what you are telling me. To be certain, in terms of at the database layer, when I need to create a temporary employee, I will be creating a new record in the Employee table and get that EmployeeID and also create a new record in the TempEmployee table with the same EmployeeID from Employee table. If so, the Employee table has many required fields. Will a schema change be needing or did I totally miss the picture?

Comment: The idea isn't to change the existing database at all - this could break the ERP system(s) dependent on it. Yes, you will need to add custom code to add the TempEmployee after the Employee has been inserted (e.g. Screen change). The only thing you may need to watch for is physical row deletion of Employee - we may need CASCADING deletes on TempEmployee. And yes, you will need to stuff any non-used fields of Employee with nulls or default / dummy values, when modelling TempEmployee as an Employee.

Comment: @StuartLC - Perfect! I finally got it and thank you very much for the insightful explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `status` field on your `Employee` table that denotes whether the employee is full time or part time. Create another table like:

```
create table temp_change_date (
    employeeID int PK (FK),
    change_date date
);
```

Populate this table with an `update trigger` on your `Employee` table when an `employee` goes from temporary to permanent.

This way the `Orders` automatically map and you can see all the orders created while they were a temp employee using the date they were changed.

Comment: The problem with this design is that "due to the different ERP systems and groups that handle the data entry" do not talk to each other and thus we cannot rely on what is in the TempEmployees "table" will match what is ultimately in the Employees table.

Comment: @frenu In this design there is no `TempEmployees` table and `Employees` table, there is just the `Employees` table since a temporary employee is still an employee. The only thing that is tracked in the above mentioned table is when the employee switched from being temporary to permanent.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying and sorry for the confusion when I noted "TempEmployee".  I should have said instead: a "temp employee" is entered via a team that is in charge of the Human Resources system (HRIS) that handles permanent employees, which is another group w/in the company. So a temp employee could be entered as "Tom Smith", but when they become a permanent employee, their official name could be "Thomas Smith". Hope this helps and thank you!

Comment: @It's still the same employee, the way their name is entered is just different. If the user is recreated just because their name is different can (and will) cause issues.

Comment: Yes, physically, they are the same person, but NOT in the database unfortunately. There is really nothing that can be done about this given the governance or the lack there of, of our employees and systems. Thank you.